# Restcomm Docker container exits after few seconds - restcommautomate.sh failed

Tags: docker, restcomm

I successfully installed Docker (Server Version: 1.10.3) on Windows 10 in order to run Restcomm image (Docker install verified according to Docker procedure).

The I followed Restcomm Docker Quick Start Guide (http://docs.telestax.com/restcomm-docker-quick-start-guide/) - in Docker Quickstart Terminal:

- pulled lastest Restcomm Docker image (`docker pull
  restcomm/restcomm:latest`)
- run Restcomm container (using: `docker run  -i -d --name=restcomm-myInstance -v /var/log/restcomm/:/var/log/restcomm/ -e STATIC_ADDRESS="192.168.99.1" -e ENVCONFURL="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/RestComm/Restcomm-Docker/master/scripts/restcomm_env_locally.sh" -p 80:80 -p 443:443 -p 9990:9990 -p 5060:5060 -p 5061:5061 -p 5062:5062 -p 5063:5063 -p 5060:5060/udp -p 65000-65050:65000-65050/udp restcomm/restcomm:latest`)
- checked Restcomm process (`docker exec b1551eea7bdc ps -ef | grep java`) - all OK
- connected & logged-in successfully to Olympus via: https://**192.168.99.100**/olympus
- connected & logged-in successfully to Restcomm Admin UI via: https://**192.168.99.100**/

Note: the IP 192.168.99.1 used for starting Restcomm was assigned to "Ethernet adapter VirtualBox Host-Only Network #2:" used by VirtualBox running Docker Host, however the IP 192.168.99.100 is reported in Docker Terminal (`docker is configured to use the default machine with IP 192.168.99.100`). Not sure if this matters.

Docker container and Restcomm was 'ON' for several hours.

Then I stopped the Restcomm container (`docker stop b1551eea7bdc`) and restarted it (`docker start b1551eea7bdc`), however after starting the Restcomm Docker container exits after roughly 20 seconds.

I removed the Restcomm container using `docker rm`, then tried to run it again using the initial command from quick start guide (`docker run  -i -d --name=restcomm-myInstance -v /var/log/restcomm/:/var/log/restcomm/ -e STATIC_ADDRESS="192.168.99.1" -e ENVCONFURL="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/RestComm/Restcomm-Docker/master/scripts/restcomm_env_locally.sh" -p 80:80 -p 443:443 -p 9990:9990 -p 5060:5060 -p 5061:5061 -p 5062:5062 -p 5063:5063 -p 5060:5060/udp -p 65000-65050:65000-65050/udp restcomm/restcomm:latest`)

Restcomm container starts but exits after few seconds - output of last ps command which shows it running: `0ccb245d1d76        restcomm/restcomm:latest   "/sbin/my_init"     18 seconds ago      Up 19 seconds       0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp, 5080-5083/tcp, 8080/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5060-5063->5060-5063/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5060->5060/udp, 5080/udp, 0.0.0.0:9990->9990/tcp, 0.0.0.0:65000-65050->65000-65050/udp, 8443/tcp, 65051-65535/udp   restcomm-myInstance`

I repeated several times the start / remove / run / ps cycle, also swapping IPs, but each time the outcome is the same - Restcomm Docker container exits before I can connect with Olympus or Admin UI.

Logs from last instance of my Restcomm container are as follows:

```
$ docker logs  0ccb245d1d76
*** Running /etc/my_init.d/00_regen_ssh_host_keys.sh...
*** Running /etc/my_init.d/restcommautomate.sh...
Will check if Enviromental variables script file is set
Configuration file URL is: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/RestComm/Restcomm-Docker/master/scripts/restcomm_env_locally.sh
url https://raw.githubusercontent.com/RestComm/Restcomm-Docker/master/scripts/restcomm_env_locally.sh /tmp/conf.sh
*** /etc/my_init.d/restcommautomate.sh failed with status 1

*** Killing all processes...
false
```

I'm not sure what has changed with respect to the the first attempt when I executed 'run' and all went OK. What else could be checked in the container?

I'm new to Docker, so the next thing I could try is to remove the Restcomm image, pull it again and repeat the process. However I'd rather solve the current issue & avoid it in the future.

Any ideas, hints would be appreciated.

Regards,

Dominik

Comment: Hi Dominik, I am running the exact command locally and it works for me. I am using linux though but this shouldn't make any difference. Please pull again restcomm/restcomm:latest and try to run it again. I don't see any particular reason you have this problem.

Comment: Hi Lefteris, indeed I removed the Restcomm image and pulled it again, run from scratch and it helped. Thanks for your suggestion.